# Is there any asynchronous up-to-date http client for RxJava?

Tags: spring, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android, project-reactor

Reactor-core and Spring 5 have just introduced the new async WebClient for their Mono/Flux Publishers.

Since it's very usual to wrap a RestTemplate request with an Observable and subscribeOn it to provide asynchronicity I was wondering if there was any async client for RxJava.

I found https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxApacheHttp but it seems to be unsupported, its last commit is from 2014, and isn't even working in my tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use RxNetty(https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxNetty) that is based on Netty.

You can also use Netflix Ribbon (https://github.com/Netflix/ribbon) together with RxNetty.

Answer (score 3):

Another option - [AsyncHttpClient](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client/tree/master/extras/rxjava2). Maven [link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.asynchttpclient/async-http-client-extras-rxjava2)

Starting point:

```
RxHttpClient.create(AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient) ;
```

Comment: You might want to add more details

Comment: AsyncHttpClient wants maintainers, so better not to use this library

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is, but it is not clear, whether is suits your needs:

[Retrofit2](https://github.com/square/retrofit)

In order to enable to get responses as `Observable` add the following to your `build.gradle` file:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
```

Among many options you have:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    (...)
    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
    (...)
    .build();
```

After that inside the class that is the interface of `Retrofit` every function can have `Observable<{class_to_return}>` as a returned object:

```
retrofit.create({interface_class}.class)
```

Interface class (example):

```
Observable<ApiUser> postLogin({parameters});
```

Comment: I just used it and unfortunately it is not an async client. I can see how the observables it returns run in the http server thread, thus blocking it.

Comment: Create a middle class, that will add appropriate operators: [subscribeOn](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribeon.html) and [observeOn](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/observeon.html)

Comment: I am already doing that using Spring RestTemplate. I am asking if there is any asynchronous web client for RxJava.